# I I install pipenv environment with "pip3 install pipenv" command and ı did but ı can't find bin folder in my .vitualenvs folder

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, importerror, virtual-environment

I  I install pipenv environment with "pip3 install pipenv" command and ı did but ı can't find bin folder in my .vitualenvs folder.I can't run "python manage.py runserver" command is giving an ImportError "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"What should ı do?

edit: my system is windows 10 pro, python 3.9.6 64.bit, django 3.2.6

in the cmd console "pip3 install pipenv"
"cd Desktop"
"mkdir django"
"cd django"
"pipenv install django"
when ı run this folder is consist but ı can't find bin folder.

I followed the steps in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHux0gMZ3Eg

Comment: Which operation system you are running?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and list each command you ran, in order.

Comment: This might be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/250442/django-installed-but-cant-import-django-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows it uses Scripts while Mac uses bin. So use **Scripts\python.exe** instead after the path.